# Deploying to Weblogic with Jenkins and getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy a .war file on Weblogic through Jenkins and am having some issues.

My Jenkins Master instance is on a Windows server and deploy is running on a slave node, also on a windows.

My problem is at the time of deploy. When calling the Weblogic deploy plugin I get the message:

```
------------------------------------  ARTIFACT UNDEPLOYMENT ----------------    --------------------------------
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -debug -remote -verbose -noexit -    name webserviceR1 -targets Cluster_WXYZ -adminurl http://server:host -user     username -undeploy
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/deploy/api/spi/DeploymentOptions
    at     weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.init(Jsr88Operation.java:70)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Operation.(Operation.java:52)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Operation.(Operation.java:47)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Operation.(Operation.java:42)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.    (Jsr88Operation.java:55)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.UndeployOperation.    (UndeployOperation.java:15)
    at     weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.newOperation(Deployer.java:218)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:86)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
    at weblogic.Deployer.main(Deployer.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     weblogic.deploy.api.spi.DeploymentOptions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException:     weblogic/deploy/api/spi/DeploymentOptions
    at     weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.handleUnexpectedException(Deployer.j    ava:118)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:95)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
    at weblogic.Deployer.main(Deployer.java:55)
Unexpected Error Initializing Deployer: weblogic.Deployer$DeployerException:     weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException:     weblogic/deploy/api/spi/DeploymentOptions
------------------------------------  ARTIFACT DEPLOYMENT ------------------    ------------------------------
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -debug -stage -remote -verbose -    upload -name webserviceR1 -source     C:\jenkins\jobs\webserviceR1\target\webserviceR1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war -targets     Cluster_WXYZ -adminurl http://server:host -user username -deploy
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/deploy/api/spi/DeploymentOptions
    at     weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.init(Jsr88Operation.java:70)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Operation.(Operation.java:52)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Operation.(Operation.java:47)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Operation.(Operation.java:42)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.    (Jsr88Operation.java:55)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployOperation.    (DeployOperation.java:18)
    at     weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.newOperation(Deployer.java:219)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:86)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
    at weblogic.Deployer.main(Deployer.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     weblogic.deploy.api.spi.DeploymentOptions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
weblogic/deploy/api/spi/DeploymentOptions
```

I have already tried using jars weblogic.jar, wlfullclient.jar and wlthint3client.jar, and none of them worked.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem ... What was happening was that I was trying to run the job using the jars of the 12C weblogic when, in the case, I should have used the wlfullclient generated by a version of weblogic server 10.3.6.

So I downloaded the weblogic 10, generated the wlfullclient from this version and it worked.